# How to make dataframe content in e-mail go red in html based off results using Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, colors

I am e-mailing a dataframe in the body of the e-mail. However, I want to format the dataframe results so that if my results are a specific value (non-0 value) then the text turns red.

Please see below for my function which I turn into a dataframe to be sent in an e-mail

```py
def id_check():
    df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', low_memory=False)
    missing_id = df["id"].isna().sum()
    print("Number of records missing an id:", missing_id)
    return missing_id

id_table = {
    'Check' : ['ID Check'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : [id_check()]
}

df_id = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(id_table)
df_id.head()
```

the result looks like

```
Check   Summary                                     Findings
0   ID Check    Number of records missing an ID     0
```

However, if the findings ever become != 0, I'd like the findings result to turn red. Is there a way to do that? Currently i am just outputting my results and by default it is black

See below for my html e-mail code.

```py
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = ','.join(TO)
    
html = f"""
    <html><body>
    <h1> </h1>
    <p> Please see the the summary below {df_id.to_html(index=False)} </p>
    </body></html>
    """
   
msg_text = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(msg_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) for coloring red row if no `0` in `Findings` column, [`Styler.hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) is for hide index, for html is used [`Styler.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html.html):

```
color= lambda x:  (pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
                         .mask(x['Findings'].ne(0), 'color:red;'))
html = df_id.style.apply(color, axis=None).hide().to_html()

#for oldier pandas version use
#html = df_id.style.apply(color, axis=None).hide_index().render()

html = f"""
    <html><body>
    <h1> </h1>
    <p> Please see the the summary below {html} </p>
    </body></html>
    """
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, what if I add more functions to my dataframe that should not turn red if findings = 0? Is there a way i can specifically say if my id_check != 0 in the case i add more functions?

Comment: I also received a 'AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'hide' running that so i am unsure what the next steps are

Comment: @bananas - Can you upgrade pandas?

Comment: @bananas - If not possible upgrade, can you try `df_id.style.apply(color, axis=None).hide_index().render()`, added to answer.

Comment: thank you jezrael! this works if i can apply it to my entire dataframe. I realize that i need to specific functions in my dataframe (I will have to add  more functions that wont need this color logic).